# HTMLNode null when selecting nodes from htmldocument

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

So I'm trying to get a soundcloud track ID, I'm not sure on how to go about this but so far I've figured out that I should be able to read a meta tag from the song's page on soundcloud. Here is my code:

```
string url = "https://soundcloud.com/hardstyle/scarphase-angernoizer-chaos-of-the-mayans-feat-tha-watcher-bkjn-vs-partyraiser-2017-anthem";
HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument d = w.Load(url);

var x = d.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head/meta[30]");
Console.WriteLine(x.InnerText);
```

I'm trying to read the following tag:

```
<meta property="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="soundcloud://sounds:322162984">
```

So I can get the content and then get the track ID

When trying to display the innertext of variable X there is nothing to display, when setting a breakpoint it says that X is null, can anyone explain me why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the attribute there is no inner text to that tag.

Use `var x = d.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head/meta[30]@content").Value;` instead. This will point your query to the content tag where you can extract the `soundcloud://...`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the attribute "content" of the node selected:

```
string url = "https://soundcloud.com/hardstyle/scarphase-angernoizer-chaos-of-the-mayans-feat-tha-watcher-bkjn-vs-partyraiser-2017-anthem";
HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument d = w.Load(url);
var x = d.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head/meta[30]").Attributes["content"].Value;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the property attribute of x
var prop = x.GetAttributeValue("property", "");
Console.WriteLine(prop );
// output: twitter:app:url:googleplay

//similarly get the content attribute of x
var content = x.GetAttributeValue("content", "");
Console.WriteLine(content );
//output : soundcloud://sounds:322162984
```

Hope this helps.